# TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxSpeechInputLength' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

im currently working on an expo project, it is failing exclusively in Android, here's my Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.17",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.15.2",
    "expo": "^48.0.19",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-auth-session": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-blur": "~12.2.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.2.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "11.1.1",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-random": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-speech": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "^0.16.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "react": "~18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "~18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.8",
    "react-native-drax": "^0.10.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-notifier": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.15.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.22.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "expo-module-scripts": "^3.0.11",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10"
  },
```

the error appeared out of nowhere and i've not been able to solve it.

I tried to go inside the expo speech folder in node_modules and find the maxSpeechInputLength, it was linked to "speechExponent" and the max input was something like 32000, i hardcoded it and still had nothing...

The error appeared out of nowhere without any major changes being done in the application, it happens exclusively in developer / simulator mode, prod is OK.

thanks.

btw i checked every impot where i use Speech and all is ok :p

Comment: Please post actual code instead of images; images are not searchable. There is no reference to `maxSpeechInputLength` here, so nobody can tell what's going on.

Comment: That is exactly the thing buddy @mykaf i do not declare anywhere the `maxSpeechInputLength`, it is native from node_modules / expo-speech module

the only reference i have is this line inside node_mdoules > expo speech > src > Speech > Speech.ts:

`export const maxSpeechInputLength: number = ExponentSpeech.maxSpeechInputLength || Number.MAX_VALUE;`

Comment: And also we have this: 
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/speech/#speechmaxspeechinputlength

it is a constant, but i have no idea where to declare it or put it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone encounters this error..

a new build solves it, a new dev build should do ok. Idk why or what happened, but there it is. love to you all, happy coding.